# how do I translate this sql to dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to do the equivalent of this SQL code:

```
SELECT Cat_1, Cat_2, Cat_3, Sum(cost), Sum(quantity) FROM tbl_of_data
GROUP BY Cat_1, Cat_2, Cat_3;
```

How do I do that using the dplyr package in R?

I tried:

```
library(dplyr)
tbl_of_data %>%
  group_by(Cat_1, Cat_2, Cat_3) %>%
  mutate(cost, quantity)
```

but I'm ending up with the same number of rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need either `summarise` or `summarise_each` to get a single row of `sum` for each combination of groups which would be equivalent to the `sql` output.

```
tbl_of_data %>%
       group_by(Cat_1, Cat_2, Cat_3) %>% 
       summarise_each(funs(sum), cost, quantity)
```

Or

```
tbl_of_data %>%
       group_by(Cat_1, Cat_2, Cat_3) %>% 
       summarise(cost=sum(cost), quantity=sum(quantity))
```

`mutate` creates a new column.  In addition, in the OP's `mutate` code, it didn't wrap with the `sum`.   If the intention is to create new `sum` columns, either `mutate` or `mutate_each` can be used i.e.  `...%>% mutate(SumCost= sum(cost), SumQuantity = sum(quantity))`  or `...%>% mutate_each(funs(sum), cost, quantity)`

Comment: oh k. I just saw mutate used elsewhere and tried to reverse engineer. Thanks :D

Comment: @KillerSnail  No problem.  Glad to help you.